# If the browser is left open for an extended period of time, website is getting crashed

Tags: asp.net, browser

We have developed a website. This will be deployed in IIS in server machine of a network. n number of people will access our website from their allocated pc's. What happens now is, if the browser is left open for an extended period of time, it is getting crashed, then i will have to reload the page to get access to my site. What should i do to overcome this problem?

Please advise on this.

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: Please submit some code from the website. Especially if you have any while loops in the backedn or ajax queries

Comment: To overcome this problem, debug your code. Seriously, how do you expect us to guess what you did wrong in your application? That said, track any memory leak using a good javascript profiler.

Answer (score 0):

You havent provided much information here so cant really comment anything specific (for e.g. runtime env, database servers, any specific tech. in use such as TCP/IP, web sockets.

There can be number of things that you could look into.

For the start you could look into resources that are not being disposed properly. For e.g. Database connection, large in memory .NET objects for e.g. file streams. Now this could be something as simple as using statements or exception handling(if .NET).

You could use profiler applications such as MiniProfiler (do google), Again if its Microsoft then you could use Microsoft Load Testing to see where the problem is.

Try using fiddler to see if it shows anything.

If you are using TCP/IP communication for e.g. push notifications from server side using websockets or node.js then you need to investigate if there are any threads/connections not properly closed/disposed.

list is sort of endless.. good luck